# Correct way to say apply powder on skin of child

Tags: phrase-requests, expression-choice

What is the proper way to say I’m applying talcum powder on my child’s body? I always wonder whether 'applying powder' is correct in this sense.

Comment: 'Powder' can be used as a verb.

Comment: The prepositions are 'put powder _on_ [the baby's bottom, baby ...]' but 'apply powder _to_ [the baby's bottom / skin / thighs etc: formal, and needs to be more specific than 'baby', probably because of incongruous registers].

Comment: Looking at the photos of products online, I'm seeing the verbs *shake*, *apply*, and *dust* in the directions on the labels. I don't know if it's OK to link to products on ELU.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say *put powder on*. It is true that *powder* is a transitive verb, but it sounds odd to me except in specific phrases, like *powder my nose*.